# Limit in a system

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, asymptotics

I have the following system of differential equations:

I want to find the $\lim_{t\to\infty}a_t$,$\lim_{t\to\infty}b_t$, $\lim_{t\to\infty}c_t$ and $\lim_{t\to\infty}d_t$.

Comment: Are you sure the sum of the equations is $0$?

Comment: Yes, there was an error in the sign of the fourth equation. I corrected it. Thank you for telling me.

Comment: The equilibrium points of the system are given by $a b = c = 0$, so a solution can converge either to $(a_\infty, 0, 0, 1 - a_\infty)$ or to $(0, b_\infty, 0, 1 - b_\infty)$. A solution can also blow up, consider the case $c_0 = 0$.

Comment: Thank you! Anyway it is not possible to characterize $a_\infty$ or $b_\infty$?

Comment: Probably not in exact form. If we consider the first three equations, then $c = 0$ is a center manifold, so the system can be approximated by a topologically conjugate system $(\dot a, \dot b, \dot c) = (-a b, a b, -c)$. Then, for small starting values, we can expect the solution to blow up when $a_0 > 0 \land b_0 < 0$ and otherwise to converge to $(0, a_0 + b_0, 0)$ when $a_0 + b_0 > 0$ and $(a_0 + b_0, 0, 0)$ when $a_0 + b_0 < 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I will try to understand well what you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

We see that $(ac)'=ca'+ac' = -abc + ac(b-1) = -ac$; thus $ac = C^2e^{-t}$. I choose the integrating constant anticipating the derivations below.

If we take the derivative of $c$ in terms of $a$, we get $c' = -C^2e^{-t}a^{-2}(a'+a)$.

We aim to find an equation only in terms of $a$. Take the derivative of the first equation to get $a''=-ab'-a'b$. Multiply by $a$ to get $aa''=-a^2b'-a'ab=-a^2b'+(a')^2$. Recognize that $a'+b'+c'=-c$, and thus after substituting expressions for $c$ and $c'$ in terms of $a$, $b'=-c-a'-c'=-\left(C^2a^{-1}e^{-t}+a'-C^2e^{-t}a^{-2}(a'+a)\right)$. Substituting this expression into the $a''$ equation and simplifying, we arrive at the following second order nonlinear equation.

$$aa''=-[C^2e^{-t}-a^2]a'+(a')^2$$

I do not think this equation has a simple closed form solution. However, consider a particular solution of form $a=k e^{-\delta t}$. Then $aa'' = k^2 \delta^2 e^{-2\delta t} = (a')^2.$ Substituting this back into the nonlinear differential, we get $C^2e^{-t} = k^2e^{-2\delta t}$, where equating constants gives us a solution $a = Ce^{-t/2}$, and consequently $a=c$. In this scenario, $b=c'/c+1=1/2$, and $d=\int c dt = \gamma_0-2Ce^{-t/2}$. Then we fit back into the initial conditions $a(0)+b(0)+c(0)+d(0)=2C+1/2+\gamma_0-2C=1$ to get $\gamma_0=1/2$

Comment: Another special case that lends to a closed form solution is if $C^2 = 0$, and allowing $c=0$. This leads to the differential equation $a' = a(D-a)$. The other case, where $a=0$ is not as pretty.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it was really useful. I have a question. Since the system is in the polinomial form, I can prove that (given an initial condition $a_0$, $b_0$, $c_0$, $d_0$) the solution exists and is unique. The solution that you propose in your answer holds in the case in which $a_0=c_0=C^2$ and $b_0=\frac{1}{2}$. Is this correct? This means that if I start with another initial condition $a(t)$ won't be of the form $k^2e^{-\delta t}$? Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you have 3 degrees of freedom (dof) in your system of equation. So the specific cases that I mentioned have reduced the number of dofs. In general, you can attempt to solve the nonlinear 2nd order equation in $a$ which will have two dofs, $a(0)$ and $a’(0)$, and then add $C$ as the third dof.